# JS form action link is used instead of link that is actually clicked

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, mobile

I just came accross the below issue in a project of mine:

1. user clicks a button
2. a js function is called to check the
   input of the form field and if accepted will submit the form to save_to_db.php in an
   iframe.
3. in the iframe, save_to_db.php will save the form details to the db and calls another js function that updates the contents of html elements on the current page showing the latest status.

This used to work without any issues (and still does in most browsers).

But now in Chrome Mobile browser version 63.0.3239 somehow every link a user clicks after they clicked the button, will load to save_to_db.php (the form action of the button) instead of the link that is clicked.

Has anyone noticed this or similiar behaviour or does anyone know how to resolve this?

Comment: the question is not very clear but based on what i understood, may be u want to prevent the form submit action, so u can use event.preventDefault(); in the function which is called while submitting the form

Comment: Please let me know what is not clear, I will try and explain. The form does need to be submitted because that is how the data will be saved to the DB.

Comment: can u share that form code

Comment: Implement a proper AJAX solution instead of using iframes?

Comment: Yes, I'm doing that on the side but I would really want to understand the logic behind this behaviour. Thank you for helping.

Comment: function submitThisForm(formname, action){ 

 var count = document.forms[formname].elements['count'].value;
 
 if(count != '0'){
    document[formname].target = "my_iframe_id";
    document[formname].action = action;
    document[formname].submit();
 } else {
    alert('nope...');
 }
}

Comment: and from what I understood iframes can make requests to other domains and sites, ajax cannot so I would still really like to understand the behavior first